# Find Neighbors in 2d array and Assign them to Cluster

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I go a table with pixel X and Y coordinates and I need to find neighbor pixels in 8 directions and assign them to a cluster.

I already build myself a recursive function which turned out to be too slow for large tables. For simplicity I use quite often panda dataframes, which might be one reason.

However, I feel like I reinvented the wheel but I am working on this for 3 days now and it seems I am too newbie to figure out any numpy or scipy function to cope this problem. Has someone an idea to speed this up?
Thanks

My MWE is:

```
def findNeighborPixel(InIniX, InIniY, InIniIndex, InClusterID, InSearchlist, InpdTable):
    
    for (x,y) in InSearchlist:
        x = InIniX + x
        y = InIniY + y

        ## Check if X & Y & no ClusterID is True and retun to FindRow
        FindRow = InpdTable.loc[(InpdTable['X-Pos'] == x) & (InpdTable['Y-Pos'] == y) & (InpdTable['ClusterID'].isnull())]

        if len(FindRow.index) > 0:
            NewIndex = FindRow.first_valid_index()
            InpdTable.loc[InIniIndex, 'ClusterID'] = InClusterID
            InpdTable = findNeighborPixel(x, y, NewIndex, InClusterID, InSearchlist, InpdTable)

            ## Make Sure, the last found Position is marked with the current Cluster ID
            InpdTable.loc[NewIndex, 'ClusterID'] = InClusterID

    return InpdTable




data = pd.DataFrame({'X-Pos': [0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,6,6],
                     'Y-Pos': [0,0,858,998,0,741,0,533,711,0,455,631,0,857,0,11],
                     'ClusterID': numpy.nan
                    })

searchlist = [
    (-1,+1), (+0,+1), (+1,+1),
    (-1,+0),          (+1,+0),
    (-1,-1), (+0,-1), (+1,-1),
    ]

ClusterID = 0

for IniIndex in range(0, len(data)):
    ## If the current row was not already assigned to a cluster
    if pd.isna(data.loc[IniIndex, 'ClusterID']) == True:
        ClusterID += 1

        IniX = data.loc[IniIndex, 'X-Pos']
        IniY = data.loc[IniIndex, 'Y-Pos']
        newData = findNeighborPixel(IniX, IniY, IniIndex, ClusterID, searchlist, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore 'KMeans' from sklearn

Without claiming that this solves you problem, for example you can do the following:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
data = pd.DataFrame({'X-Pos': [0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,6,6],
                     'Y-Pos': [0,0,858,998,0,741,0,533,711,0,455,631,0,857,0,11],
                     'ClusterID': np.nan
                    })
                    
coords = data[['X-Pos','Y-Pos']].values
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0).fit(coords)
data['ClusterID'] = kmeans.labels_
data.sort_values('ClusterID')
```

output

```
      X-Pos    Y-Pos    ClusterID
--  -------  -------  -----------
 0        0        0            0
 1        1        0            0
 4        2        0            0
 6        3        0            0
 9        5        0            0
12        5        0            0
14        6        0            0
15        6       11            0
 5        2      741            1
 8        3      711            1
11        5      631            1
 7        3      533            2
10        5      455            2
 2        1      858            3
 3        1      998            3
13        5      857            3
```